# Trying ClientProtocolProvider : org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider

Tags: java, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

I am running a mapreduce application in a multi-node cluster, My application is not launching a mapreduce job as its not able to pickup org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider as the ClientProtocolProvider - returned null protocol

In return its picking up LocalClientProtocolProvider, where that machine doesn't have all the hadoop services running.

[09 Nov 2017 00:20:20,371] [Thread-0] [op.mapreduce.Cluster] [DEBUG] [Trying ClientProtocolProvider : org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider]
[09 Nov 2017 00:20:20,371] [Thread-0] [op.mapreduce.Cluster] [DEBUG] [Cannot pick org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider as the ClientProtocolProvider - returned null protocol]
[09 Nov 2017 00:20:20,371] [Thread-0] [op.mapreduce.Cluster] [DEBUG] [Trying ClientProtocolProvider : org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalClientProtocolProvider]
[09 Nov 2017 00:20:20,372] [Thread-0] [trics.jvm.JvmMetrics] [INFO] [Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized]
[09 Nov 2017 00:20:20,372] [Thread-0] [op.mapreduce.Cluster] [DEBUG] [Picked org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalClientProtocolProvider as the ClientProtocolProvider]

How do we set application to use YarnClientProvider instead of LocalclientProtocolProvider.

Any help or sugestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. My configuration object in Driver was not able to pick mapreduce.framework.name as "yarn". It was getting as local, So it was picking up LocalClientProtocolProvider instead of YarnCleintProtocolProvider.